# Mindate as one month from current date in datetime picker in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using datetime picker for date. For that, I am removing time. Everything is working fine but mindate is not working. I want to select mindate as one month back from the current date. I have tried all the ways. Please help me, thanks in Advance.

```
$("body").delegate(".extend_date,.modify_date", "focusin", function(){
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            format: 'd-m-Y',
         //i have used -1m,-1M,-30D,-30d but nothing works for me
            minDate: '-30d',
            timepicker: false,
            maxDate: new Date,
            changeMonth: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are certain that this is the *jQuery UI DateTimePicker* (which uses `minDate`), and not the *Bootstrap jQuery DateTimePicker* (which uses `startDate`)? Given that you've mentioned other properties (like `maxDate`) working, perhaps this clarification isn't entirely necessary, but I've found it's a fairly common source of confusion related to datetimepicker questions.

Comment: Yes this jquery datetime picker only